# General formula for trapezium bases if angles and height, and one base are known

Tags: geometry

Lets assume that I have a trapezium $ABCD$, in which $AB$ is parallel to $CD$.  Angles

∠$DAB$ = ∠$ABC = 126$°
∠$BCD$ = ∠$CDA = 54$°

If I assume that the height $h$ is known, and the longer base $CD$ is known, is there a general formula for finding the short base $AB$ ?

The angles are specific. Five of these trapezium will form a hollow pentagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The shorter side AB will be $CD-2\tan(54^\circ) h$. This can be seen by dropping altitudes through the ends of the shorter side $AB$ and then subtracting off the two pieces of $CD$ located beyond the two altitudes.

Comment: I have edited it so it is clearer that $AB$ is the shorter base and $CD$ the longer.